# select multi range with .find, .findnext variable (copies EMPTY cells)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with the following code which you can see below. It is totally a pain in the *** now. I really need some help.
This code is a search tool which looks for criteria from every worksheet except the summary and the list. After the .Find founds the word, then the code selects a 4 wide range around the searched word, then it copies and pastes it on the Summary sheet.
When the first searched word is found, I also would like to copy and paste the actual worksheet (where the word is found) title (on each worksheet "G3:J3") right after the search result on the summary page. This search tool could help me to find quickly which search criteria where can be found, at which sheet and some properties which also inside the title.

The result should look like this: (r1 = the first 4 columns, r2= the rest 4 columns (that is the excel header))

item nr.    Item    Owner   Used Capacity   ESD_nr.     box Owner   Free capacity   location

Sorry for the long description.

CODE:

```
Private Sub searchTool()

Dim ws As Worksheet, OutputWs As Worksheet, wbName As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, multiRange As Range
Dim strName As String
Dim count As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim IsValueFound As Boolean

IsValueFound = False
Set OutputWs = Worksheets("Summary")    '---->change the sheet name as required
lastRow = OutputWs.Cells(Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
strName = ComboBox1.Value
If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> "lists" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then

        With ws.UsedRange

            Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = rFound.Address

                Do

                IsValueFound = True
                Set r1 = Range(rFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B"), rFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "D"))
                Set r2 = Range("G3:J3")
                Set multiRange = Application.Union(r1, r2)
                multiRange.Copy
                OutputWs.Cells(lastRow + 1, 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

                Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> firstAddress

            End If
        End With
    End If
Next ws
On Error GoTo 0
If IsValueFound Then
   OutputWs.Select
   MsgBox "Seach complete!"

Else
    MsgBox "Name not found!"
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I had trouble following your requirements and there was not a definition of where it wasn't working, to that end I re-wrote it to help me understand.

```
Private Sub SearchTool_2()
Dim BlnFound        As Boolean
Dim LngRow          As Long
Dim RngFind         As Excel.Range
Dim RngFirstFind    As Excel.Range
Dim StrName         As String
Dim WkShtOutput     As Excel.Worksheet
Dim WkSht           As Excel.Worksheet

StrName = "Hello" 'ComboBox1.Value
If StrName = "" Then Exit Sub

Set WkShtOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    LngRow = WkShtOutput.Cells(WkShtOutput.Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (WkSht.Name <> "lists") And (WkSht.Name <> "Summary") Then
            With WkSht.UsedRange
                Set RngFind = .Find(What:=StrName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not RngFind Is Nothing Then
                    Set RngFirstFind = RngFind
                    BlnFound = True
                    Do
                        WkSht.Range(RngFind.Address & ":" & WkSht.Cells(RngFind.Row, RngFind.Column + 2).Address).Copy WkShtOutput.Range(WkShtOutput.Cells(LngRow, 11).Address)
                        WkSht.Range("G3:J3").Copy WkShtOutput.Range(WkShtOutput.Cells(LngRow + 1, 11).Address)
                        LngRow = LngRow + 2
                        Set RngFind = .FindNext(RngFind)
                    Loop Until RngFind.Address = RngFirstFind.Address
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
Set WkShtOutput = Nothing

If BlnFound Then
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Select
   MsgBox "Seach complete!"
Else
    MsgBox "Name not found!"
End If

End Sub
```

I found the copy statement was the better option rather than using the clipboard, I also found a missing reference of `firstAddress`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I only had to change the first range to `WkSht.Range(RngFind.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B"), RngFind.EntireRow.Cells(1, "E").Address).Copy WkShtOutput.Range(WkShtOutput.Cells(LngRow, 11).Address)` But many thanks! :)